# Getting Eclipse on PC

Tags: java, installation

I'm in a computer science class and have used this site as a reference from time to time.

I apologize that this isn't inherently a "programming" question, but I'm really in a panic and need some help here.

I use Eclipse Java 32 bit on the computers at school, but the lab is closed today and I have a programming assignment due. How could I get Eclipse on my PC for writing java? I would need windows 32 bit.

I know this isn't what this site is fore, but please help as I am really panicking right now and I know you guys know your stuff on here

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQXX6KyGWBQ

Comment: Google "eclipse" and go to their download page?

Comment: did you even bother to google "eclipse 32 bit windows download" ? i understand your panicking behavior being a college student is a stressful thing but please try and good things a little more next time. What are professors teaching there students now a days anyways? I think lesson #1 in a class should probably be "teach student how to install programming software, plugins and frameworks/libraries"

Comment: Are you talking about installing Java itself? You'll need the JDK to compile anything on your home PC.

Comment: Yeah I am finding it comical that I have learned so much in the class, yet I don't even know the first thing about what I'm _actually_ doing. Thanks for the help but I'm still lost as fff....

Answer (score 2):

Simply download eclipse and unzip into a directory. There is no installer, just a dump. Run eclipse.exe from the base folder and enjoy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

Its basically very simple as Eclipse is open source IDE.you should go to www.eclipse.org/download/ and get a copy of eclipse from there according to your requirement. I would recommend eclipse classic if you are beginner and programming platform is Java.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is available for free at http://www.eclipse.org.

More specifically, all latest Windows versions are available from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=win32.

The 32bit version for Java EE Developers can be found at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/SR2/eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32.zip.

Included in this .zip is an installer package for your PC.

Comment: I watched that exact video before posting here. The problem is that after I downloaded it, I got some WinRAR program and the logo was a pile of textbooks, not the purple thing...

Comment: @user2348722 so you're in a CS class and you are totally clueless about all things related to computers?  I mean, basic stuff like zip files, unpacking, copying files?  Wow, just wow.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: Read First**
Wait. Are you talking about actually installing Java?

**Original Post:**
As the good guy I am, I countered that negative vote for you, but it might not last.

As a IT/CS student myself, I thought you'd be capable of programming without Eclipse.

You can use Notepad++ just as easily http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Otherwise Netbeans https://netbeans.org/ is just as good and installs much quicker than Eclipse IMO. But eclipse can be run just from the package itself - but it is a much larger download if you're pressed for time.